# If I don't use def rewind()..than what can I do to print 3 lines separately

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."
rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `seek(0)` is the simplest way to re-read the contents of a file. Alternatively, you can simply `close()` the file and `open()` it again.

But you can't always `seek()` (or re-open) a file-like object, eg if it's a terminal or a pipe. So if you need to access its contents multiple times you should read it once, saving its contents into a string, or even better, into a list of lines. You can use `.readlines()` to read the file directly into a list of lines, or you can `.read()` it into a string and then use the `str.splitlines()` method to create a list from that string.